# How to open and for-loop over the lines of a file using argv argument from command-line (in C)?

Tags: c, file, for-loop

Right now, I have a main function that looks like (argv[2] is the file I want to loop over, from the command-line)

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
   FILE *thisfile;
   thisfile = fopen(argv[2], "r");
   while ....
}
```

I want to eventually be able to loop over each line of the file, argv[1] and see if any of the lines contain a string, which is argv[1]. I know of the C operations like fgets, but I am not sure how to use them. So for now, outputting each line of the file is enough, but after I'd like to see if each line contains a string. I am very new to C, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Make an attempt first.

Comment: you do this with a `while` loop, not a `for` loop.

Comment: There must be hundreds of tutorials on the web that show how to read from a file in a loop. SO is not a tutoring service.

Comment: Why do you think it matters that the filename came from argv? You read a file the same way no matter where you got the name.

Comment: I looked at multiple other questions asked on stack overflow and they weren't very helpful. Also, they all were pseudocode, not reading in from argv, which made it confusing. I don't know how else to get the filename other than from argv. Also remyabel, I did make an attempt, and it didn't work, I didn't want to post non-working code.

Comment: Non-working code is better than no code.

Answer (score 0):

the first question is easy,the code just like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1024



int main(int argn, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    fp = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    while(fgets(line, MAXLINE, fp) != NULL)
        printf("The line is:%s\n", line);
    return 0;
}
```

but your second question(find a string in one line) has many ansower,it's pattern recognize,if you want ,you can google kmp.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. However, can you tell me what the line "char line[MAXLINE]" does? Is it just making a char array of size 1024? I don't understand how fgets uses it as an argument.

Comment: fgets is an interface of standard  io, you can google it for more detail.Casue you are a freshman in c,you can read a book about c,most of them will give you example of   how those interface use and work.